# Print the largest String with the shortest Code

Tags: code-golf, string

As the title says, your task is to print the largest string using the shortest code without taking any input value.

### Rules

- The program must take no input and print the largest string to STDOUT
- The string must contain only ASCII Characters. If you don't know the ASCII Characters, take a look at the [table](https://www.asciitable.com/)
- No Loops are allowed
- No multiplication, exponentiation or any kind of elevation is permitted.
- The score is measured by subtracting the amount of bytes of your code to the amount of bytes of your string. Example. My code is `60` Bytes and it generates an string of `300` Bytes. My score will be `300-60=240`
- The highest score wins.

### Example

```js
try{a.b}catch(e){alert(e)}
```

The output of my program is `ReferenceError: a is not defined` = 32 bytes

My Score will be `32-26` = 6

---

### Update

By Loops i mean any repetitive structure. For example `for`, `while`, `do while`, `recursive functions` etc..

Comment: Generating a 65535x65535 image and printing its content base64 encoded? Sounds allowed, but horribly boring.

Comment: `while True:print(1)` prints indefinitely so has score infinity. ez

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/13074/68942), though that one is closed for Too Broad.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino No Loops are allowed

Comment: Right, sorry, missed that. How do you define "loop" though?

Comment: is string replacing allowed? is recursion allowed? is decompressing allowed? are  `eval`  type things allowed?

Comment: By Loops i mean any repetitive structure. For example `for`, `while`, `do while`, `recursive functions` etc.. Let me add that into the question

Comment: That's still not an objectively observable requirement.

Comment: Might I suggest posting in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to get feedback before posting challenges? This type of challenge is tough to specify, but it's possible it can be saved with some additional effort and requirements.

Comment: @Giuseppe I guess that's what i'm gonna do.

Comment: Because it's subtraction and not ratio of lengths, how do you prevent people from just repeating a function that gives positive score like 1000000 times?

Comment: The shell utility `yes` by definition has ∞ output, though is not explicitly a loop in the shell language.  Allowed?

Comment: println(arc+arc+...+arc);
The full code cannot fit here. the ... means the + arc goes forever.

Comment: If program `P` scores `S`, then you can construct a program that scores `2*S` by repeating the source of `P` twice.

Comment: [you can print some character arbitrary many times without loops like so](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z85I7FIoTg61rY62kBBT0/P0tIy1tbMVCcazDCotc5NzMzT0KwuKC0p1ijWtK79/x8A)

Comment: [Related: Maximizing output from minimal input](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67255/maximizing-output-from-minimal-input), [related: Shortest code for longest output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13074/shortest-code-for-longest-output), [related: Largest number in ten bytes of code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31695/largest-number-in-ten-bytes-of-code).

Comment: If you're requiring unobservable behavior, you're doing somthing wrong 99% of the time, mostly "assume language features".

Comment: Oh I wish this was open!! WinDBG: `d0 L?FFFFFFFF` would get an absurdly high score! It'll dump the whole address space, as bytes and ASCII value, plus there's spaces, new lines, ticks, and hyphens for formatting, as well as the address offset every 0x10 bytes. If I did my math right, it'll score about `9.6845406e+19`. The length of the program at this point is insignificant.

Comment: I like the python print(2\**2\**2\**2\**2\**2\**2). Users should take care to purchase sufficient system RAM

Comment: @Alpha3031 "No multiplication, exponentiation or any kind of elevation is permitted."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## R, 541-9 = 532

When passing a built-in function name to R, the console describes it parameters.  I'm sure there are longer ones, but I went for the low-hanging fruit

Code:

```
.packages
```

Output:

```
function (all.available = FALSE, lib.loc = NULL) 
{
if (is.null(lib.loc)) 
    lib.loc <- .libPaths()
if (all.available) {
    ans <- character()
    for (lib in lib.loc[file.exists(lib.loc)]) {
        a <- list.files(lib, all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE)
        pfile <- file.path(lib, a, "Meta", "package.rds")
        ans <- c(ans, a[file.exists(pfile)])
    }
    return(unique(ans))
}
s <- search()
invisible(.rmpkg(s[substr(s, 1L, 8L) == "package:"]))
}
<bytecode: 0x103fdf200>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Edit:  Thanks Giuseppe for the [link](https://tio.run/##K/r/X68gMTk7MT21@P9/AA)

Comment: @dzaima seems right

Comment: You can add a link to [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K/r/X68gMTk7MT21@P9/AA) so we can verify your results! And welcome to R golfing, by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 937

```python
help()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyM1p0BD8/9/AA)

Comment: Wouldn't `help()` or `import this` have better code/output ratio?

Comment: @manatwork oh yeah thanks